# String formatting with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have numbers in table and need to format them with JavaScript (2 symbols after dot).
This code works but I guess there are more efficient and elegant ways:

```
var str = "126389471.74000001";
var dotIndex = str.indexOf(".");
var formattedStr = str.substring(0, dotIndex+3);
```

Could anybody suggest better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you treat them as strings in the first place? It would be much better to use JavaScript to automatically handle this with [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var num = 126389471.74000001,
    formatted = num.toFixed(2);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/drw6Y/)

If you absolutely **have** to treate it as a string, use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and the same method:

```
var formatted = parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `toFixed`

```
var str = "126389471.74000001";
var formattedStr = parseFloat(str).toFixed(2); // 2 dp
```